# Different results in computing KL Divergence using Pytorch Distributions vs manually

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I noticed the KL-Divergence term KL(Q(x)||P(x)) is computed differently when using

```
mean(Q(x)*(log Q(x) - log P(x)))
```

vs

```
torch.distributions.kl_divergence(Q, P)
```

where

```
Q = torch.distributions.Normal(some mean, some sigma)
P = torch.distributions.Normal(0, 1)
```

and when I plot the KL-divergence losses, I get this two similar but different plots:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoX2b.png)

Can anyone point out what is causing this difference?

The full code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.distributions as dist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def kl_1(log_qx, log_px):
    """
    inputs: [B, z_dim] torch
    """
    return (log_qx.exp() * (log_qx-log_px)).mean()

# ground-truth (target) P(x)
P = dist.Normal(0, 1)


mus = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
sigma = 1
N = 100
kls = {"1": [], "2": []}
for mu in mus:
    # prediction (current) Q(x)
    Q = dist.Normal(mu, sigma)
    
    # sample from Q
    qx = Q.sample((N,))
        
    # log prob
    log_qx = Q.log_prob(qx)
    log_px = P.log_prob(qx)
    
    # kl 1
    kl1 = kl_1(log_qx, log_px)
    kls['1'].append(kl1.numpy())
    
    # kl 2
    kl2 = dist.kl_divergence(Q, P)
    kls['2'].append(kl2.numpy())
    
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(mus, kls['1'], label="Q*(logQ-logP)")
plt.scatter(mus, kls['2'], label="kl_divergence")
plt.xlabel("mean of Q(x)")
plt.ylabel("computed KL Divergence")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the sample weighted by the probability density if you are computing the expected value from an integral on `dx`. If you are using a sample from the given distribution then you approximate the expected value as the mean directly, that corresponds to integration on `d cq(x)` thus `d cq(x) = q(x) dx`, where `cq(x)` is the cumulative probability function, and `q(x)`  id the probability density funciton of the variable `Q`.

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.distributions as dist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def kl_1(log_qx, log_px):
    """
    inputs: [B, z_dim] torch
    """
    return (log_qx-log_px).mean()

# ground-truth (target) P(x)
P = dist.Normal(0, 1)


mus = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
sigma = 1
N = 100
kls = {"1": [], "2": []}
for mu in mus:
    # prediction (current) Q(x)
    Q = dist.Normal(mu, sigma)
    
    # sample from Q
    qx = Q.sample((N,))
        
    # log prob
    log_qx = Q.log_prob(qx)
    log_px = P.log_prob(qx)
    
    # kl 1
    kl1 = kl_1(log_qx, log_px)
    kls['1'].append(kl1.numpy())
    
    # kl 2
    kl2 = dist.kl_divergence(Q, P)
    kls['2'].append(kl2.numpy())
    
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(mus, kls['1'], label="Q*(logQ-logP)")
plt.scatter(mus, kls['2'], label="kl_divergence")
plt.xlabel("mean of Q(x)")
plt.ylabel("computed KL Divergence")
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Do you mean "that corresponds to integration on dq(x)"(not dp(x)) in the last sentence?

Comment: Yes I messed the terms, and also that differential is of the cumulative probability function.